# How to apply this material to text?

Tags: materials

I did this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvxcy8ISsHE
and would like to apply the material to some text, this is what happened when I tried. 
[image]

Comment: did you UV unwrap the mesh?  Could you show the uv?

Comment: I didn't, doh! That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: no problem, glad that helped!